# Host Webservice In Winforms Application

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have a winforms application which I need it to host a web service. I was actually thinking about using a HttpListener and return a standard wsdl file as a response, how ever I keep getting an error message saying that my wsdl is not formatted correctly when testing it from SoapUI.

Do you know anyway to make it ?
Or, perhaps you know a commercial .net control that can generate web services from code dynamically ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could [self-host](http://dotnetstories.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/self-hosting-wcf-services/) a WCF service within your WinForms application. In that link they are doing it in a Console application but the technique is equally applicable to a WinForms application.

Note that this isn't a common use case (AFAIK) and it seems that sometimes people run into some problems (if you go a Google on something like "WCF service host in WinForms"). If you're backed into a corner on this design choice, there are also some questions about it on Stack Overflow, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267071/how-can-a-self-hosted-winform-wcf-service-interact-with-the-main-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718244/wcf-in-winforms-app-is-it-always-single-threaded) which might be useful to read as well.